# How to fix 'unsafe-member-access' react typescript error with cloneElement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to fix a lint error:

`Unsafe member access .className on an any value  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access`

---

I believe I have to correctly type the `cloneElement((element: SOME_TYPE)`, but am unsure how to do this!

```
element: React.ReactNode;

....

{React.isValidElement(element)
    ? React.cloneElement(element, {
          className: classNames(
              element.props.className,
              "absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0 w-full h-full"
          ),
          ref: elementRef,
      })
    : element}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
  const hasClassName = (props: unknown): props is {className: string} => typeof props === 'object' && Object.hasOwnProperty.call(props, 'className');
  let childClassName = '';
  if (hasClassName(element.props)) {
    childClassName = element.props.className;
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).